# Pygame Platformer Scrolling Bug

Tags: python, pygame

So while working on my engine, I wanted to add an enemy in there, sounded simple enough. Even though my enemy is in the game, not violating the laws of physics (for the most part), the weird part is that I gave him 0 control over movement, but the enemy keeps following the player sprite as I move along.

Now playing around for a bit I've noticed the enemy latches on to the scrolling viewbox while the player is moving, hence the enemy slightly jumps when the player jumps as he hit the down viewbox.

I'm not trying to give him any AI at the moment, the enemy just needs to spawn along with the player, drop to a platform and stand still as the player moves away.

## The whole code:

```
from pygame import *
import time
import pygame
# from colours import *
# from textObjects import small, medium, large

###########################################################################
#   COLOURS AND TEXT OBJECTS                                              #
###########################################################################

black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
grey = pygame.Color(128, 128, 128)
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)

red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)

green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)

light_blue = pygame.Color(201, 242, 255)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)

green_yellow = pygame.Color(212, 255, 0)
yellow = pygame.Color(255, 251, 0)
orange = pygame.Color(255, 166, 0)
orange_red = pygame.Color(255, 85, 0)

pygame.font.init()
small = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
medium = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
large = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 80)

###########################################################################
#   CLASSES                                                               #
###########################################################################


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
# Initialise function
    def __init__(self, color=blue, width=32, height=48, health=100):
        # I assume super() inherits everything from the block class
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        # Set the image to a Surface of size width and height
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        # Fill the image with the default color of blue
        self.image.fill(color)
        # Use the Surface of the image to get the rectangular co-ordinates
        self.set_properties()
        # Create speed for x and y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        # Create health
        self.health = 100
        self.level = None

    def set_properties(self):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Create an x and y origin position (Centered the mouse on the sprite)
        self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.origin_y = self.rect.centery
        self.speed = 5
        # Create total travel distance to check the player's position on the map
        self.travel_distance_x = 0
        self.travel_distance_y = 0

    # Function to easily set the position of any block object on the center
    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x - self.origin_x
        self.rect.y = y - self.origin_y

    # Function made to print the position on the map
    def print_position(self):
        self.travel_distance_x += self.speed_x
        self.travel_distance_y += self.speed_y
        # print self.travel_distance_x, self.travel_distance_y

    def set_level(self, level):
        self.level = level
        self.set_position(level.player_start_x, level.player_start_y)

    def set_image(self, filename=None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
            self.set_properties()

    def update(self, collidable=pygame.sprite.Group(), event=True):
        self.experience_gravity()
        self.event = True
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x

        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            # Right direction
            if self.speed_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = collided_object.rect.left
            # Left direction
            elif self.speed_x < 0:
                self.rect.left = collided_object.rect.right
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y
        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            # Down direction
            if self.speed_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = collided_object.rect.top
                self.speed_y = 0
            # Up direction
            elif self.speed_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = collided_object.rect.bottom
                self.speed_y = 0
        if not event == None:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.speed_x = -self.speed
                    # self.change_speed(-self.speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.speed_x = self.speed
                    # self.change_speed(self.speed, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if len(collision_list) >= 1:
                        self.speed_y = -(self.speed) * 2
                        # self.change_speed(0, -self.speed * 2)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    # self.change_speed(0, self.speed)
                    pass
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if self.speed_x < 0:
                        self.speed_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    if self.speed_x > 0:
                        self.speed_x = 0

    def experience_gravity(self, gravity=0.35):
        if self.speed_y == 0:
            self.speed_y = 1
        else:
            self.speed_y += gravity


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
# Initialise function
    def __init__(self, color=red, width=32, height=48, health=100):
        # I assume super() inherits everything from the block class
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        # Set the image to a Surface of size width and height
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        # Fill the image with the default color of blue
        self.image.fill(color)
        # Use the Surface of the image to get the rectangular co-ordinates
        self.set_properties()
        # Create speed for x and y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        # Create health
        self.health = 100
        self.level = None

    def set_properties(self):
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Create an x and y origin position (Centered the mouse on the sprite)
        self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.origin_y = self.rect.centery
        self.speed = 5
        # Create total travel distance to check the player's position on the map
        self.travel_distance_x = 0
        self.travel_distance_y = 0

    # Function to easily set the position of any block object on the center
    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x - self.origin_x
        self.rect.y = y - self.origin_y

    # Function made to print the position on the map
    def print_position(self):
        self.travel_distance_x += self.speed_x
        self.travel_distance_y += self.speed_y
        print self.travel_distance_x, self.travel_distance_y

    def set_level(self, level):
        self.level = level
        self.set_position(level.enemy_start_x, level.enemy_start_y)

    def set_image(self, filename=None):
        if filename != None:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
            self.set_properties()

    def update(self, collidable=pygame.sprite.Group(), event=True):
        self.experience_gravity()
        self.event = True
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x

        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            # Right direction
            if self.speed_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = collided_object.rect.left
            # Left direction
            elif self.speed_x < 0:
                self.rect.left = collided_object.rect.right
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y
        collision_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
        for collided_object in collision_list:
            # Down direction
            if self.speed_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = collided_object.rect.top
                self.speed_y = 0
            # Up direction
            elif self.speed_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = collided_object.rect.bottom
                self.speed_y = 0
        if not event == None:
            pass

    def experience_gravity(self, gravity=0.35):
        if self.speed_y == 0:
            self.speed_y = 1
        else:
            self.speed_y += gravity



class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color=blue):
        # I assume super() inherits everything from the block class
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        # Set the image to a Surface of size width and height
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        # Fill the image with the default color of blue
        self.image.fill(color)
        # Get rectangle object of the block
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Assign x and y co-ordinates of the block
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def experience_gravity(self, gravity=0.35):
        if self.speed_y == 0:
            self.speed_y = 1
        else:
            self.speed_y += gravity

class Level(object):
    def __init__(self, player_object):
        self.object_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player_object = player_object
        self.player_start = self.player_start_x, self.player_start_y = 80, 150
        self.enemy_start = self.enemy_start_x, self.enemy_start_y = 300, 200

        self.world_shift_x = 0
        self.world_shift_y = 0

        self.left_viewbox = screen_width / 2 - screen_width / 8
        self.right_viewbox = screen_width / 2 + screen_width / 8
        self.up_viewbox = screen_height / 3
        self.down_viewbox = screen_height / 2 # + screen_height / 12

    def update(self):
        self.object_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.fill(white)
        self.object_list.draw(screen)

    def shift_world(self, shift_x, shift_y):
        self.world_shift_x += shift_x
        self.world_shift_y += shift_y
        for each_object in self.object_list:
            each_object.rect.x += shift_x
            each_object.rect.y += shift_y


    def scroll(self):
        if self.player_object.rect.x <= self.left_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.left_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.left_viewbox
            self.shift_world(view_difference, 0)

        if self.player_object.rect.x >= self.right_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.right_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.right_viewbox
            self.shift_world(view_difference, 0)

        if self.player_object.rect.y <= self.up_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.up_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.up_viewbox
            self.shift_world(0, view_difference)

        if self.player_object.rect.y >= self.down_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.down_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.down_viewbox
            self.shift_world(0, view_difference)


class Level_01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player_object):
        super(Level_01, self).__init__(player_object)
        level = [
            #[x, y, width, height, color]
            [0, 0, 38, 899, black],
            [7, 874, 1592, 25, black],
            [1564, 0, 35, 887, black],
            [0, 0, 1593, 40, black],
            [330, 731, 282, 31, black],
            [898, 678, 307, 28, black],
            [603, 528, 280, 28, black],
            [1279, 616, 301, 32, black],
            [1046, 468, 194, 35, black],
            [208, 348, 306, 28, black],
            [708, 294, 335, 24, black],
            [22, 487, 170, 26, black]
        ]

        for block in level:
            block = Block(block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3], block[4])
            self.object_list.add(block)


class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_function, width, height):
        self.camera_function = camera_function
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_function(self.state, target.rect)


###########################################################################
#   TEXT AND UI FUNCTIONS                                                 #
###########################################################################


def set_message(text):
    global message, previous_message
    message = font.render(text, True, black, white)
    previous_message = message


def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == 'small':
        textSurface = small.render(text, True, color)
    if size == 'medium':
        textSurface = medium.render(text, True, color)
    if size == 'large':
        textSurface = large.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def display_message(text, color, y_displacement=0, size='small'):
    textSurface, textRectangle = text_objects(text, color, size)
    textRectangle.center = (screen_width / 2), (screen_height / 2) + y_displacement
    screen.blit(textSurface, textRectangle)


def health_bar(player_health):
    if player_health > 85:
        health_color = green
    elif player_health > 70:
        health_color = green_yellow
    elif player_health > 55:
        health_color = yellow
    elif player_health > 40:
        health_color = orange
    elif player_health > 25:
        health_color = orange_red
    else:
        health_color = red

    if player_health < 0:
        player_health = 0

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, health_color, (50, screen_height / 20, player_health, 25))

###########################################################################
#   INITIALISATION, SCREEN PROPERTIES, FPS                                #
###########################################################################

# Initialise pygame module
pygame.init()

# Initialise pygame font
pygame.font.init()

# Defining the screen size
screen_size = screen_width, screen_height = 800, 600

# Setting the display and getting the Surface object
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

# Getting the Clock object
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Setting a title to the window
pygame.display.set_caption("TODO make title")

# Defining variable for FPS
fps_limit = 60

# Clear the screen
screen.fill(white)

# Setting the FPS at which the game will run
clock.tick(fps_limit)

###########################################################################
#   MAIN LOOP, PAUSE AND DEATH FUNCTIONS                                  #
###########################################################################


def death():
    death = True
    while death:
        display_message("YOU DIED", red, size='large')
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        death = False
        over = True
        game_exit = True


def pause():
    paused = True
    display_message("Paused", black)
    pygame.display.update()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()


def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    run=True
                    intro=False
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        screen.fill(light_blue)
        display_message("Physics Engine v0.1", black, - screen_height / 5, 'large' )
        display_message("pre-alpha stage", grey, - screen_height / 10, 'small')
        display_message("Press ENTER to start or ESCAPE to close", black, screen_height / 8, 'small')
        pygame.display.update()


def main_loop():
    # Group all the currently active objects
    active_object_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # Set variable player to the Player() class
    player = Player()

    # Set variable enemy to the Enemy() class
    enemy = Enemy()

    # Add player to the active object list
    active_object_list.add(player, enemy)

    # Make a list for the levels and append Level_01 to that list with player as the handler (being the character in focus)
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))

    current_level_number = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_number]

    # Set the starting co-ordinates
    player.set_level(current_level)
    enemy.set_level(current_level)

    # run = True
    over = False
    game_exit = False
    while not game_exit:
        if over == True:
            while over:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        game_exit = True
                        over = False
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == K_RETURN:
                            main_loop()
                        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                            pygame.quit()
                            quit()
                screen.fill(light_blue)
                display_message("Do you want to start over?", black, -screen_height / 8, size='large')
                display_message("Press RETURN to start over or ESCAPE to quit", black, screen_height / 8)
                pygame.display.update()
        current_events = pygame.event.get()
        if current_events:
            for event in current_events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                    run = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        pause()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_k:
                        player.health -= 5

                # Update functions
                player.update(current_level.object_list, event)
                enemy.update(current_level.object_list, event)
                current_level.update()

        else:
            player.update(current_level.object_list, None)
            enemy.update(current_level.object_list, None)
            current_level.update()

        # Logic testing
        current_level.scroll()
        if player.health <= 0:
            player.health = 0
            over = True
            death()
        if player.travel_distance_y > 900:
            player.health = 0
            over = True
            death()

        # Draw everything
        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_object_list.draw(screen)
        health_bar(player.health)

        # Delay fps
        clock.tick(fps_limit)

        # Update screen
        pygame.display.update()

game_intro()
main_loop()
```

The viewbox located in the Level class works in a way that checks if the player is hitting the box, if it is, the world is shifted around the player instead of the player moving in it.

### Scroll function

```
def shift_world(self, shift_x, shift_y):
        self.world_shift_x += shift_x
        self.world_shift_y += shift_y
        for each_object in self.object_list:
            each_object.rect.x += shift_x
            each_object.rect.y += shift_y


    def scroll(self):
        if self.player_object.rect.x <= self.left_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.left_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.left_viewbox
            self.shift_world(view_difference, 0)

        if self.player_object.rect.x >= self.right_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.right_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.x
            self.player_object.rect.x = self.right_viewbox
            self.shift_world(view_difference, 0)

        if self.player_object.rect.y <= self.up_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.up_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.up_viewbox
            self.shift_world(0, view_difference)

        if self.player_object.rect.y >= self.down_viewbox:
            view_difference = self.down_viewbox - self.player_object.rect.y
            self.player_object.rect.y = self.down_viewbox
            self.shift_world(0, view_difference)
```

A thing to note is that Level and Level_01 takes "player_object" as an input, which I think is called when player.update() and enemy.update() are called in the main loop.

### Main loop

```
if current_events:
            for event in current_events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                    run = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        pause()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_k:
                        player.health -= 5

                # Update functions
                player.update(current_level.object_list, event)
                enemy.update(current_level.object_list, event)
                current_level.update()

        else:
            player.update(current_level.object_list, None)
            enemy.update(current_level.object_list, None)
            current_level.update()
```

So despite the fact that player is used as a handler for the level in line 477:

```
level_list.append(Level_01(player))
```

I think the enemy is influenced by the viewbox because he is also treated as the "player_object" in the scrolling function.

If anyone can give me a few tips on what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `scroll`, or rather your `shift_world` function. You shift every object in `self.object_list`. For Level01, this list only contains the block objects. In `scroll`, you then shift every block and the player, *but not the enemy*. This means the enemy sprite stays at its place and is not shifted with the world as it should be. It therefore appears to move, because its position relative to the world changes. In truth, it stays blitted at the same position on the canvas as it was.

When the player jumps, the enemy ends up in the air once the world has shifted down, and then gravity pulls him back to the platform. When the player moves right, the enemy seems to follow because the world shifts left and the enemy doesn't shift with it.

Add the enemy to your `object_list` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Now I feel rather silly, it indeed fixed that, thanks!

Comment: Just noticed after a map change the enemy shoots infinitely upwards, I made enemy as a global variable, added him to the object list in the Level_01 function. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without the whole code. If by map change you mean level change, wouldn't you want a new enemy for every level? To debug, check what parts of your code change the position of your enemy and try to isolate the function that causes this. The debugger of your IDE may come in handy. If the problem persists, it's probably best to open a new question and try to post a minimal working example that shows this behavior.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ACdp000j this would be the code. By the change just using a different set of platforms in there. Funny thing I've just noticed the enemy flies upwards so fast it goes though the platform and gets stuck on the other side of it. Thanks for the tips, debugging will now commence.

Comment: You added enemy to `current_level.object_list`, which means when you call `enemy.update(current_level.object_list, event)` the enemy collides with itself and adjusts its vertical position accordingly. Also, there's no need to make enemy global, simply pass it to the Level the same way you pass the player object.

Comment: Okay, finally got it to work, all I needed was for the enemy to be an independent list in the Level class (such as object_list) so I could still call the update function with the `current_level.object_list` without colliding with itself. Gravity on the enemy is a bit faster than for the player, but at this point I absolutely do not care. Thank you for all of your help, really appreciate it!